# Streaming data(images) from Storage Bucket to training job on google AI-platform

Tags: gcloud, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am running a training job using keras. The entire code is computationally heavy and the size of the number of images it should be training on is around 30GB. The training images are stored on Google storage. I have created a docker container for my training script and every works well according to the plan. I noticed that the images are being copied into the VM that is being allocated and copying the images from Google storage to the training job takes about 1 and half hour. This is increasing the training time and is not suitable for me as the number of images keep growing on a weekly basis by atleast 1GB. I have previously worked with AWS training jobs which gave me an option for file transmission from S3 to Sagemaker training job where the input can be 'pipe' into the training job. Is there a similar service in google cloud or is there a better solution rather than copying all the files to the VM allocated to the training job?

Comment: Is your training script in your Storage bucket ? According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#using_gcloud_to_package_and_upload_your_application_recommended), it is recommended to use gcloud to package and upload your application. Also,  this (link)[https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-keras] it shows this approach which may clarify it.

Comment: I have a custom training script/ image and stored in the container registry and one runs the training job, the image is pulled from there. The data required for the training is stored on the Storage bucket. Now when the training job is run, the data is copied onto the VM that is initiated by the training job. As the data is about 30GB, it takes a lot of time to copy the data before it starts training. I have heard one can mount the buckets using gcfuse. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: according to the [documentation Cloud FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#notes), this feature has much higher latency than a local file system. Also, it is not recommended to run over a database to Cloud FUSE. For this reason, I m  not sure if it will solve your issue. I will have a closer look to the documentation and check if there is any other work around.

Comment: When you train your model, specify the --region flag in your  gcloud command. The region should be the same region of your GCS bucket so that operation will be done within the same region (e.g same data center) and this will make the copying of the images fast. In the documentation "Create your Cloud Storage bucket in this region and, later, use the same region for training and prediction." https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-keras#create_a_bucket

Comment: @Christopher It still takes the same amount of time. Probably reduces by 5-10 minutes. Not more than that.

Comment: @Macintosh1997, Have you considered using Online Predictions instead of Batch ? Because this feature is optimized to minimize latency of serving predictions even though, with both predictions you pass the data to a cloud-hosted ML model. Besides that, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-vs-batch-prediction) a Batch prediction can take several minutes while the Online prediction can return the results almost instantly.Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Thank you for your response. Serving the model as Batch or Online is fine. But before that can be done, the model has to be trained. The entire issue occurs when trying to train the model.

Comment: @Macintosh1997, thanks for your response. I understood that your training data is around 30gb, then will you retrain your model every week for the new coming data? I suggested online prediction because I understood this new data was going to be used to retrieve predictions.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Yup. The model will be retrained weekly with the new data that is coming in.

Comment: @Macintosh1997, I understand now. After thinking a bit more about your issue, I believe you could use a custom scale tier to train your model and increase the number of workers, which would make the job runs faster, or use one of the pre confihured scale tiers, you can read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/machine-types#scale_tiers). This would increase your performance. Could you try this?

Comment: Also, since you mentioned you will retrain your model every week, which is a bit unsual. I need to point that, generally, we have 3 types of data: the train data which we use to train our model, then test data which we use to check the accuracy and, lastly, the we want to get predictions from. Furthermore, as a bonus information, according to GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/local),it is possible to train your model locally. Did any of this info help you?

Comment: @Macintosh1997, do you have any updates?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Let's say one is in a situation where there are 15 to 20 additional classes of images being added every week, in that case, I think training you model for all the additional classes makes sense. I have since changed the pipeline, removed the data preparation to a seperate container and zipping all the files required. I hope this works. I will keep you updated.

Comment: @Macintosh1997, I understand. If you have additional classes of images every week it makes sense train your model with this new classes or new features. I believe it will work. Keep me updated! Also, if you found any of the information i shared with you helpful I would appreciate if you could upvote and accept the answer I posted to further contribute with the community.

Answer (score -1):

I am posting this answer with all the information I shared in the comment section.

According to the documentation it is advisable to use ***gcloud package*** to upload you application. In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#using_gcloud_to_package_and_upload_your_application_recommended), you can find more about defining your system's environment variables as well as submitting your training job.

Regarding you comment about [Cloud FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#notes), it is an open source adapter which allows you to mount *Cloud Storage Buckets* as file systems on *Linux* or *MacOS*. Therefore, applications can interact with the mounted bucket like in a simple file system, providing virtually limitless storage if running in the cloud. However, in your case it is not recommended because it has much higher latency than a local file system. For this reason, it is also not recommended to run a database over ***Cloud Storage FUSE***, you can read more about its limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#notes).

Since you reported that your problem is with the training time. I would recommend you to use a custom tier to train your model, increasing the number of workers. Thus, the job would run faster. In addition, you can use the pre-configured tiers described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/machine-types#scale_tiers).

Just as a bonus information, when your model is trained, consider using ***Online predictions*** over ***Batch predictions***. Online predictions are optimized to minimize latency of the results even though, you pass the data to a cloud-hosted ML model in both cases. Besides that, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-vs-batch-prediction) a Batch prediction can take several minutes while the Online prediction can return the results almost instantly.